# How do I set the background color of a brush style

Tags: python, qt5, qbrush

I tried the following code which gives me an orange crosspattern on white background and I would like it to be blue for example.

```
brush = QtGui.QBrush()
brush.setColor(QtGui.QColor('orange'))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.CrossPattern)

scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)

it = scene.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 400, 400))
it.setBrush(brush)

view.resize(640, 480)
view.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

my work arround was to create a child rectangle with the pattern and a different zvalue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).